# No network interface in QEMU

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, qemu

My network interfaces never shows up in my guest computer.

I'm compiling a linux kernel (3.3 I think) from scratch with default settings +

```
Symbol: NE2K_PCI [=y]
Type  : tristate
Prompt: PCI NE2000 and clones support (see help)
```

since I read somewhere that this is the default driver that qemu uses.

I'll then boot with:
`qemu-system-x86_64 -kernel repo/linux/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -boot d -initrd rootfs.img.gz -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init"`

qemu-system-x86_64 -nographic  -kernel repo/linux/arch/x86/boot/bzImage  -boot d -initrd rootfs.img -append "root=/dev/ram rdinit=/sbin/init console=ttyS0"

The rootfs is simply busybox's `_install` dir + /proc /dev and such and etc/init.d/rcS

```
#!/bin/sh
mount -t proc none /proc
mount -t sysfs none /sys
/sbin/mdev -s
```

But I can't find the interface after boot. `ifconfig -a` simply shows the loopback interface.

From http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Ethernet-HOWTO-2.html I understood that I should look at ??`System.map` file for names like `ne_probe`. But can't find anything about that really.

My boot output is:
http://pastebin.com/C2SmKjQA

And cat /proc/ioports doesn't show anything about ne2k-pci, as it's expected to, according to http://www.h7.dion.ne.jp/~qemu-win/HowToNetwork-en.html.

Comment: I was trying to search for "freebsd qemu network interfaces missing" and didn't get her from google, the on-site search worked though. Thank your for the details! Using interface type e1000 worked right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, you should have user mode networking as explained in the docs:

> By default QEMU will create a SLiRP user network backend and an appropriate virtual network device for the guest (eg an E1000 PCI card for most x86 PC guests)

If you want something better, consider `tap` networking:

Add something like the following to your `qemu` command:

```
-netdev tap,id=tap0 -device e1000,netdev=tap0
```

or for older versions of `qemu`:

```
-net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no
```

Be aware that they need you to start `qemu` as root and also may require configuration of the host networking.

More info available on [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/QEMU/Networking) and in the [QEMU Networking docs](http://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking).

Comment: I've used "-net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no" to not use user mode network. But I guess device is the important parameter Im missing?

Comment: netdev=network0 is that so I can identify it with id=network0 in -netdev?

Comment: The `-device` and `-netdev` method is the newer way of configuring devices. It replaces `-net`. Correct: `network0` is the identifier that ties the two together.

Comment: I now have my eth0! Though those parameters didnt have any effect... I added e1000 to the kernel and got the interface, both with and without those parameters. Any hints on why?

Comment: @DavidEverlöf - Just found this in the QEMU docs, which probably explains it: By default QEMU will create a SLiRP user network backend and an appropriate virtual network device for the guest (eg an E1000 PCI card for most x86 PC guests).

Comment: Ah, ok! Seems appropriate! Ill accept you answer, since it got it me in the right direction! The problem was that I wasnt compiling it with: E1000E=y and E1000=y. Dont really know which of these that solved it! Anyway, thank!